# Edit Method for Hashmap EmployeeStore

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, edit

I am making an EmployeeStore that will store names, dob, id, email address etc... and i need to write an edit method.  I have googled and i cannot find how to do this can anyone help? Here is my code:

```
//Imports.
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************  
public class MainApp
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));
//Test Code with the new Hashmap.       
        /*Store.print();
        Store.clear();
        Store.print();

        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));

        Store.print();
        Store.remove("Andy Carroll");
        Store.print();*/
//********************************************************************  
        //Switch Statement for use of a menu.
         int choice;
            do {
                choice = getMenuChoice("1.\tLibrarian\n2.\tPublic User\n3.\tExit\n\n", 3, "Please enter choice:", "Error [1,3] only");
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Librarian Functionality...\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Public User functionality...\n");

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Program Finished");

                }
            }
            while (choice != 3);
}
//********************************************************************  
      public static int getMenuChoice(String menuString, int limit, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
      {
            System.out.println(menuString);
            int choice = inputAndValidateInt(1, limit, prompt, errorMessage);
            return choice;
       }
//********************************************************************  



        public static int inputAndValidateInt(int min, int max, String prompt, String errorMessage) {
            int number;
            boolean valid;
            do {
                System.out.print(prompt);
                number = keyboard.nextInt();
                valid = number <= max && number >= min;
                if (!valid) {
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                }
            } while (!valid);
            return number;
        }
//********************************************************************  
}


//Imports:

//********************************************************************
//Employee Class.
public class Employee
{
//Variables.
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//********************************************************************  
//Constructor.
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//********************************************************************
//Getters.
    public String getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
//********************************************************************
//toString method.
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employeeName=" + employeeName + ", employeeId="
                + employeeId + ", employeeEmail=" + employeeEmail + "]";
    }
//********************************************************************





}
//Imports.
import java.util.HashMap;
//********************************************************************
import java.util.Map;

public class EmployeeStore 
{
    HashMap<String, Employee> map;

//Constructor.  
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    }
//********************************************************************
//Hashmap Methods.
//Add to the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void add(Employee obj)
    {

        map.put(obj.getEmployeeName(), obj);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Remove from the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void remove(String key)
    {
      //Remove the Employee by name.
        map.remove(key);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Clear the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void clear()
    {
        map.clear();
    }
    //********************************************************************
//Print the Hashmap : Employee. 
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Employee's in the Company.********");
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + employee.getEmployeeName());
            System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + employee.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println("E-mail:\t"+ employee.getEmployeeEmail());
        }

    }


//********************************************************************  
//********************************************************************


}
```

Comment: public  Item searchForID(int id){
        Item e = null;
        for(int i = 0; i<items.size();i++){
            e = items.get(i);
            if (e.getId()==id){
                break; i have this from an ArrayList but i cant get it to work for a hashmap

Comment: Too complicated. Use the HashMap.get(K). Check my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to fetch the Employee object from the HashMap, then modify the object. For example, to change the email:

```
//in class EmployeeStore
String email = somehowGetNewEmail();
Employee toEdit = map.get(somehowGetName());
toEdit.setEmail(email)
```

Alternately:

```
//in EmployeeStore
public Employee get(String name){
    return map.get(name);
}

//in any class with reference to an EmployeeStore "store"
store.get(name).editSomething(something);
```

Comment: @ConorPendlebury Yeah, but you'll need to add a `EmployeeStore.get(key)` method.

Comment: @ConorPendlebury You need a method `get()` in `EmployeeStore` to access the `HashMap` within that class. That will then allow you to access `Employee`s you have stored within the `EmployeeStore` and edit them.

Comment: Like the getters and setters in the Employee class ?

Comment: @ConorPendlebury Kind of. You're providing access to `map` within `EmployeeStore`. Basically, `EmployeeStore` is what one might call a "wrapper." It provides access to an object within it. So, for example, your `EmployeeStore.toString()` gives a better `toString()` than `HashMap`; the same is true (or at least that's the idea) for the other methdos in `EmployeeStore`. However, you don't have a method that provides external access to objects already stored within `map`, so you need to create a method `get()` that accesses them and provies them externally, like I showed in the second option.

Comment: Oh right now things are starting to get a bit clearer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap stores references to objects. That means when you read ("get") an object from a HashMap and make changes to its attributes, the changes will be carried over without you having to write it back to the HashMap.

So all your edit method has to do is call map.get(name) and make the changes to the returned Employee object. Note that you can not change the key of the HashMap that way. In order to "rename" an employee, you have to remove the value of the old key from the hash map and insert it under a new key.

Comment: You can call `HashMap.put(key, value)` and it will overwrite the value for that key and return the old value for the key, or `null` if there was none. However, this is unnecessary, as `Employee` is mutable.